# preg_match not working with variable

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I receive string from user, and pass it to preg_match to match with pattern (as output variable)

```
$regex = '/(?<L_Hostname>\S+).+?Software,\s(?<L_Platform>\S+).+?\((?<L_IOS_Type>.+?)\),\sVersion\s(?<L_IOS_Versioon>.+?),.+?#\s(?<CDP_R_Device_ID>.+)\sIP address: (?<CDP_R_IP_Address>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})\sPlatform:\s(?<CDP_R_Platform>.+?),\sCapabilities:\s(?<CDP_R_Capabilities>.+?)\s\Interface:\s(?<CDP_L_Interface>.+?),\sPort ID \(outgoing port\):\s(?<CDP_R_Interface>.*?)\sVersion.+?Version\s(?<CDP_R_Version>.+?)/i';

if(preg_match_all($regex,$output, $matches))
{
    $result->regex = $regex;
    $result->variable = serialize($matches);
    $result->save();
}
```

but above code not work and result is empty array. when I print output and copy to subject its work

```
$regex = '/(?<L_Hostname>\S+).+?Software,\s(?<L_Platform>\S+).+?\((?<L_IOS_Type>.+?)\),\sVersion\s(?<L_IOS_Versioon>.+?),.+?#\s(?<CDP_R_Device_ID>.+)\sIP address: (?<CDP_R_IP_Address>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})\sPlatform:\s(?<CDP_R_Platform>.+?),\sCapabilities:\s(?<CDP_R_Capabilities>.+?)\s\Interface:\s(?<CDP_L_Interface>.+?),\sPort ID \(outgoing port\):\s(?<CDP_R_Interface>.*?)\sVersion.+?Version\s(?<CDP_R_Version>.+?)/i';

$output = ' nano- nano-# Software, C880 Software (C880DATA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(4)M4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2) nano-# apk-sw3750.ali IP address: 192.168.1.240 Platform: cisco WS-C3750-24TS, Capabilities: Switch IGMP Interface: FastEthernet1, Port ID (outgoing port): FastEthernet1/0/3 Version : Cisco IOS Software, C3750 Software (C3750-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.2(46)SE, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2) nano-# ';

if(preg_match_all($regex,$output, $matches))
{
    $result->regex = $regex;
    $result->variable = serialize($matches);
    $result->save();
}
```

Comment: What's different between 2 code segments?

Comment: Then what exactly is not working?

Comment: In first code result of preg_match is empty but second return correct result

Comment: Then **answer properly what is different between 2 code segments**

Comment: `$output` is blank or does not exist before the `preg_match` call. You should run `var_dump($output)` before the call to ensure it is actually set.